# Почему штрих-код сгенерированный Zxing отображается узкой полоской?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Всем добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему сгенерированный штрих-код в приложении  отображается узкой полоской?

[image: пример]

Добавляю на страницу через xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView x:Name="Barcode"
            BarcodeFormat="CODE_39"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="100" Margin="10" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Значение штрих-кода задаю в коде

```
Barcode.BarcodeValue = "10348180";
```

Пробовал много вариантов, но без особого успеха. Через код почему-то не получается, штрих-код на странице не отображается.
Подскажите, если сталкивались.
Буду рад любому совету.
Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте задать width and height в ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions

Comment: Попробовал. Добавил: `Barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 100;`
`Barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 300;` . Из разметки соответственно убрал. На странице - пусто :( Почему же почему...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск решения моего вопроса обернулся внезапным успехом! Я попробовал пример, где генерировался QR-code, и он заработал сразу. Далее, я попробовал изменить формат штрих-кода на нужный мне - и на странице нормально отобразился штрих-код!

[image]

Делал через код :

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KOD = "103865998";

        var qrCode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
        {
            BarcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
            BarcodeOptions = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                Height = 100,
                Width = 350
            },
            BarcodeValue = KOD,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children = { qrCode }
        };

        this.Content = stack;

    }
```

Вот так.