# Почему ZXing не генерирует штрих-код в многостраничном приложении Xamarin.Forms Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Прошу Вашей помощи. Не так давно была проблема с генерацией этого самого штрих-кода, которая разрешилась. Вот ссылка на обсуждение: [Почему штрих-код сгенерированный Zxing отображается узкой полоской?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907892/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%88%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-zxing-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Аналогичным образом пытаюсь отобразить штрих-код в своём приложении, на третьей по счёте странице - и терплю неудачу. В версии под андройд - штрих-код не генерируется. В версии под UWP - всё работает отлично!

Я да же не могу сообразить, куда начать копать... :( В чем может быть проблема?

Вот код для страницы с штрих-кодом:

```
public Page3()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var qrCode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView() 
    {
        BarcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
        BarcodeOptions = new QrCodeEncodingOptions() 
        {
            Height = 100,
            Width = 350
        },
        BarcodeValue = Collector.StrihKod,
        //BarcodeValue = KOD,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
    };
    Label label01 = new Label() { Text = Collector.StrihKod, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#77d065") };
    Label label02 = new Label() { Text = "Where is a barcode ?", BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#77d065") };

    StackLayout stack = new StackLayout()
    {
        Children = { label01, qrCode, label02 }
    };

    this.Content = stack;
}
```

Вот результат выполнения кода

[image: Page3]

Буду очень рад любой идее!
Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите данный ответ на SOen может поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105986/zxingbarcodeimageview-qr-code-showing-on-ios-but-not-on-android-xamarin-forms

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись! Да, не найдя аналогичной ситуации и толкового описания по продукту, я стал пробовать все решения что попадались по теме и смотреть на результат. И получилось найти решение.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь, ответ на вопрос получилось найти самому...так же случайно в общем-то, как и на аналогичный вопрос по теме ZXing. Надеюсь, что кому-нибудь пригодится.
Решение нашёл на просторах инета. [Ссылка](https://skycliffs.com/2018/07/12/zxing-qr-code-display-in-xamarin-forms/) на оригинал.

В разметку страницы я добавил:

```
<zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView
                x:Name="barcode"
            BarcodeFormat="CODE_39"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300"
            HeightRequest="150"
            Margin="5"/>
```

А в код страницы:

```
barcode.BarcodeOptions = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions()
        {
            Height = 100,
            Width = 350
        };
        barcode.BarcodeValue = Collector.StrihKod;
```

И всё получилось!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]